# Checking condition and checking three separate "objects" to perform a calculation

Tags: c#, razor, comparison

I am overthinking what is probably very simple for you geniuses. :)

I have separate inputs for three different types of assets which all have the same four choices:

1. None
2. One
3. Two
4. Three or more

I am separately calculating a cost for the total quantity of particular assets that the user chooses. Each asset adds $100 to the cost, and I have it thusly in my code:

```
public static decimal priceAsset { get { return 100; } }
```

So for each separate type of asset I calculate:

1. User chooses none = $0
2. User chooses "One" = `priceAsset`
3. User chooses "Two" = `priceAsset * 2`
4. User chooses "Three or more" = `priceAsset * 3` (I also add a note that every asset above three adds $100 each).

Now, bear in mind that I do this separately for three different types of assets. These assets are property, vehicles, or "other" assets (in that order). The order, I think, is important, because the inputs are linear -- the user starts with property and has to make a choice before moving to vehicle or "other".

This works swimingly in my calculations, but now I've decided that if a certain separate unrelated condition is true in my application, then I don't want to charge $100 for the first asset only (of any asset type).

My problem is that I cannot properly figure out the logic to compare any of the two other assets to determine whether or not one or more was selected to make the determination about whether or not to charge the first $100.

If that's not clear let me give an example: I am basically telling people the first asset will not incur a $100 charge, but every asset thereafter will.

- User picks "One", "Two", or "Three or more" of asset type property, there is no charge for the first property, but two or more assets of type property incur a $100 charge each, and the same for any quantity of asset type vehicle or "other".
- User picks "None" of asset type property, but picks "One", "Two", or "Three or more" of asset type vehicle, there is no charge for the first vehicle, but two or more assets of type vehicle incur a $100 charge each, and the same of any quantity of asset type "other".
- Same for "Other" asset.
- "None" for all three types of assets just returns $0.

Here is an example of how I do property (code distilled):

```
        if One
            {
               priceAsset 
            }
        else if Two
            { 
               priceAsset * 2
            }
        else if ThreeOrMore
            {                
                priceAsset * 3
            }
        else
            { 
                $0
            }
```

I do the same for Vehcile and OtherAsset.

Now, if this were only one type of asset I could just make the first "$0" and change the second and third to easily do this, but it's in checking the other two types of assets where I falter. I started to literally compare all other assets with `||`, but that's 11 comparisons and I thought there was an easier way. Plus I am thinking I'd have to do that on every branch (so 11 * (3 asset types * 3 branches each), and well, that just sounded ridiculous.

Any guidance is much appreciated. I hope I was descriptive enough (but not overly so).

Comment: This is a very long question.  You might get better answers if you can distill it down.

Comment: I get that some will just gloss over, but in my experience more detail gets higher quality responses, particularly for a complex question such as this (at least to me). Besides, I've been on the other side of not providing enough detail and then getting minuses (at the worst), or requests for more details. Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, you are mixing code with objectives. Additionally UI specifics (like Model.StepAssetInfromation.RealEstateDropDown ) are distracting and do not help make the question clearer

Comment: I see your point and tried to cut down the code.

Comment: I second the other commenters- I'm confused because you're including so much detail.

Comment: How would you tell if property, vehicle, or other is picked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're saying is, you want to charge the same (pattern) for all asset types, except in the case where its a property and one was selected (in this case you want the value to be 0)

Assuming Enums like this:

```
public enum AssetType {
    Property,
    Vehicle,
    Other
}
public enum AssetCount {
    None,
    One,
    Two,
    ThreeOrMore
}
```

You can use this function to determine the price:

```
public static decimal GetPrice( 
        AssetType assetType, 
        AssetCount assetCount, 
        decimal unitPrice 
    ) {

        //Handle Exceptional case first
        if( assetType == AssetType.Property ) {
            if (assetCount == AssetCount.One){
                return 0;
            }
        }
        switch( assetCount ) {
            case AssetCount.None:
                return 0;
            case AssetCount.One:
                return ( unitPrice );
            case AssetCount.Two:
                return ( unitPrice * 2 );
            case AssetCount.ThreeOrMore:
                return ( unitPrice * 3);

        }
        throw new Exception( "Unsupported AssetCount" );
}
```

Comment: No, not just for property, but for the first asset. Or at least that's how I read the question.

Comment: Yes, not just for property, but first asset chosen. However, this is leading me in the right direction. Will update with results

Comment: Answering your comment above: there is no real mechanism for telling "How" something is picked. I relented to the comments and cut down the original if/else code which originally gave more insight into "How". Basically, was just doing something like this: `if (Model.StepAssetInformation.RealEstateDropDown == StepAssetInformation.RealEstate.One)`